# Test VM in GIT repository

Tags: git, testing, project-management, repository, virtual-machine

I have a project which uses TCP/IP communication to communicate with a server.
For my project, i have setup a server in a VM which i use for my tests.
When i run my tests, the VM starts, my tests run, and the VM will be closed after the test run.

Because my VM belongs to my project-resources, i want to add it to my repository.
There is only one problem, my VM is 6.5 GB and i have a GIT repository.

GIT always notes: Do not store big files in the repository.
And i do want to avoid this.

How should i arrange this in my project?
Should i store the VM elsewhere? (And retrieve it when i need it)
Or do I have other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store it elsewhere. Test machines are part of the environment, like compilers or external libraries, and not part of the source. Thus, they don't belong into the source control system.

For very project-specific files, a common pattern is to store an URI identifying the machine (e.g. using rsync://) and a checksum in the git and let your build system fetch the machine.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, adding the VM to your repository is a Bad Idea.  You may want to consider looking at something like [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) which allows you to set up VMs via VirtualBox but you only need to store the scripts necessary to boot up the VM how you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the entire VM to the GIT repo is a bad idea. Your VM is a test box it's not part of the development.

I have a similar situation, in my case the test VM is a CentOS box. So my i have done the following:

I have a batch system that can auto-configure a vanilla VM without my server code. Once it's launched I can, optionally push my server software packages to the new vm and you continue doing the rest from there...